# How to create a file with the .aidl extension in Linux?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, intentservice, aidl

I'm currently using a Linux terminal and each time I try to save a aidl file it saves it as a text file.

I also tried converting the files but it didn't work for the aidl extension :(

`mv IRemoteService IRemoteService.htm`l (Converted successfully to HTML file)

`mv IRemoteService IRemoteService.aidl` (Still saves as txt file)

When I try to build the project with the above file (IRemoteService.aidl), I get the below error:

```
interface IRemoteService should be declared in a file called com/service/IRemoteService.aidl.
```

I'm relatively new to Linux and hence unaware if there is a efficient/easier way to accomplish this. Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure it's not your ide/ compiler that is confused? Linux doesn't pay that much attention to file extensions if anythign file extensions are a nicety for help people and potentially other programs understand what kind of file something is.

Comment: how do you know that its txt file?

Comment: @Maxim: I right clicked on the file, clicked properties and under the Basic tab, I see Type: plain text document (text/plain)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It turns out I just had to put the file in the above directory structure. Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just had to put the file in the above directory structure.